# Conda install spyder for python 3.3 enviroment - Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I am using Anaconda in Windows 10. I have created an environment for python 3.3 because I want to use FBX libraries. FBX does not support python 3.6

The name of my environment is **py33**

Then, I tried to install spyder:

```
conda install -n py33
```

But, I have this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.3*
  - spyder -> chardet >=2.0.0
  - spyder -> python 2.7*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I tried to install before an after the activation of the environment. Always the same error. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to use Python 3.3? It is 3 versions out of date, and (to my understanding) all Python 3.3 code should work more-or-less as is in Python 3.6. This error specifically means that not all of the dependencies of Spyder are available for Python 3.3. You either have to build them yourself, or upgrade your Python

Comment: @darthbith
As I said, because [FBX](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_2F3A42FA_4C19_42F2_BC4F_B9EC64EA16AA_htm) does not support python 3.6

Comment: You could try copying the code to the 3.6 directory, and see if it works... :-) Sorry, I missed that in your post :-)

Comment: No, it does not work. @darbith, you were right: Spyder is not available for Python 3.3

Answer (score 0):

Well, after several trials the only solution is to build Spyder from the source code. Or use python 2.7
There is not a spyder package available for python 3.3

I think I will use python 2.7, and wait until FBX supports python 3.6